# Tag-Synonyms for [android-appcompat] and specific versions

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

I wanted to propose some tag-synonyms for [android-appcompat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-appcompat):

```
appcompat-v7
appcompat-v7-r21
appcompat-v7-r22.1
appcompat-v7-r22.2
appcompat-v7-r23
appcompat-v7-r23.1
appcompat-v7-r23.2
appcompat-v7-r24
appcompat-v7-r25
```

but I get

```
Failed to propose synonym:
Version specific synonyms can only be created by moderators
```

All of these tags were created for the specific version but they actually are referred to the exact [android-appcompat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-appcompat) support library.

Appcompat support library v28 is (and will be) the last release, and in my opinion, today there are no reason to have all these tags which could be merged in the master tag [android-appcompat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-appcompat).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I normally wait for the requests to get some comments before jumping onto them immediately, but [I don't think I need to question you](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/android-appcompat/topusers) at all.

I've added the following as synonyms:

- [appcompat-v7-r25](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/appcompat-v7-r25) (x 3) → [android-appcompat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-appcompat) (x 2178)
- [appcompat-v7-r24](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/appcompat-v7-r24) (x 8) → [android-appcompat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-appcompat) (x 2178)
- [appcompat-v7-r23.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/appcompat-v7-r23.2) (x 8) → [android-appcompat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-appcompat) (x 2178)
- [appcompat-v7-r23.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/appcompat-v7-r23.1) (x 3) → [android-appcompat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-appcompat) (x 2178)
- [appcompat-v7-r23](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/appcompat-v7-r23) (x 119) → [android-appcompat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-appcompat) (x 2178)
- [appcompat-v7-r22.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/appcompat-v7-r22.2) (x 38) → [android-appcompat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-appcompat) (x 2178)
- [appcompat-v7-r22.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/appcompat-v7-r22.1) (x 122) → [android-appcompat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-appcompat) (x 2178)
- [appcompat-v7-r21](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/appcompat-v7-r21) (x 66) → [android-appcompat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-appcompat) (x 2178)
- [appcompat-v7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/appcompat-v7) (x 18) → [android-appcompat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-appcompat) (× 2178)

I will merge them after a couple of weeks so that the questions in that tag are available in searches as well. The fact that we had a tag that was as specific as "Android AppCompat Version 7 Revision 23.1" still makes me a bit surprised, though.